# Using netbootxyz for PXE server

Tags: pxe, subiquity

Has anyone used netbootxyz autoinstalltion method with the new installer?
More specifically what is required to have a base installation with that methodology.

I am currently using the legacy installer with preseeds but I no longer find this a good option since the installer is missing some of the dynamic options it has.

In the options for netbootxyz you are getting way of pointing the files for the autoinstallation.
But for some reasons with the tested from https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall
it is not working.

Could you advise if I should store the files into a folder or else?